# What is the convention for describing a method on a certain class in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, oop, syntax

Is there an accepted convention/syntax for referring to a specific method on a given class when writing things like git commit descriptions?

Maybe something like `(NSArray *) -count:` or similar?

I keep getting fed up writing the "xxx method on class yyy"

Comment: why not do like other languages, and show how it's called: `[NSArray count:]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common notation:

```
- [NSArray count]
```

For class methods:

```
+ [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:]
```

For protocols:

```
- [id <UITableViewDataSource> tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]
```

Comment: Not only a common notation, but also the notation used by the debugger in the first two cases.